# Figures and tables indexes

Tags: indexing, latex, tex

I would like my figures index and tables index to appear in my main index (content table). By default, they aren't, so I've been trying to include them using:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Índice de figuras}

\listoffigures

\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\roman{page}}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
```

But when I do that, the minitocs of the following chapters are placed incorrectly. I mean, minitocs move towards next chapters.

I will show my problem with pictures:

[image: Index]

As you can see, the list of figures now appears in the index. But if I check my 1st chapter, there is no minitoc. It has been placed on the 2nd chapter.

[image: Chapter 2 with the minitoc of chapter 1]

Comment: You should consider posting something that replicates the problem. As it stands, it's not entirely clear what could be the cause.

Comment: The TeX SE might be a better place to ask this.